# 'no applicable method' for applying dbplyr's sql_render to a data.frame

Tags: r, dbplyr

I was testing an example from RStudio about "render SQL code" from dbplyr:

```r
library(nycflights13)
ranked <- flights %>%
  group_by(year, month, day) %>%
  select(dep_delay) %>% 
  mutate(rank = rank(desc(dep_delay)))

dbplyr::sql_render(ranked)
```

But when run, it returns the following error message:

> Error in UseMethod("sql_render") :
> no applicable method for 'sql_render' applied to an object of class "c('grouped_df', 'tbl_df', 'tbl', 'data.frame')"

Can someone explain why?

Comment: `flights` is a `data.frame`, not something that `dbplyr` needs to deal with. You're asking it to `sql_render` a normal R frame. If you look at just `ranked`, you'll see that it is `A tibble: 336,776 x 5`, grouped by `year, month, day [365]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are working on a "normal" `data.frame`, then it returns a frame, in which case `sql_render` is inappropriate (and will be very confused). If we work with just your initial code, then we can see that SQL has nothing to do with it:

```
library(dplyr)
library(nycflights)
ranked <- flights %>%
  group_by(year, month, day) %>%
  select(dep_delay) %>% 
  mutate(rank = rank(desc(dep_delay)))
ranked
# # A tibble: 336,776 x 5
# # Groups:   year, month, day [365]
#     year month   day dep_delay  rank
#    <int> <int> <int>     <dbl> <dbl>
#  1  2013     1     1         2  313 
#  2  2013     1     1         4  276 
#  3  2013     1     1         2  313 
#  4  2013     1     1        -1  440 
#  5  2013     1     1        -6  742 
#  6  2013     1     1        -4  633 
#  7  2013     1     1        -5  691 
#  8  2013     1     1        -3  570 
#  9  2013     1     1        -3  570 
# 10  2013     1     1        -2  502.
# # ... with 336,766 more rows
```

But `dbplyr` won't be able to do something with that:

```r
library(dbplyr)
sql_render(ranked)
# Error in UseMethod("sql_render") : 
#   no applicable method for 'sql_render' applied to an object of class "c('grouped_df', 'tbl_df', 'tbl', 'data.frame')"
```

If, however, we have that same `flights` data in a database, then we can do what you are expecting, with some minor changes.

```r
# pgcon <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), ...)     # to my local postgres instance
copy_to(pgcon, flights, name = "flights_table")  # go get some coffee

flights_db <- tbl(pgcon, "flights_table")
ranked_db <- flights_db %>%
  group_by(year, month, day) %>%
  select(dep_delay) %>% 
  mutate(rank = rank(desc(dep_delay)))
# Adding missing grouping variables: `year`, `month`, `day`
```

We *can* see some initial data, showing the top 10 rows of what the query will eventually return:

```r
ranked_db
# # Source:   lazy query [?? x 5]
# # Database: postgres [postgres@localhost:/]
# # Groups:   year, month, day
#     year month   day dep_delay    rank
#    <int> <int> <int>     <dbl> <int64>
#  1  2013     1     1        NA       1
#  2  2013     1     1        NA       1
#  3  2013     1     1        NA       1
#  4  2013     1     1        NA       1
#  5  2013     1     1       853       5
#  6  2013     1     1       379       6
#  7  2013     1     1       290       7
#  8  2013     1     1       285       8
#  9  2013     1     1       260       9
# 10  2013     1     1       255      10
# # ... with more rows
```

and we can see what the real SQL query looks like:

```r
sql_render(ranked_db)
# <SQL> SELECT "year", "month", "day", "dep_delay", RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY "year", "month", "day" ORDER BY "dep_delay" DESC) AS "rank"
# FROM "flights_table"
```

Realizing that, due to the way `dbplyr` operates, we don't know how many rows will be returned until we `collect` it:

```r
nrow(ranked_db)
# [1] NA

res <- collect(ranked_db)
nrow(res)
# [1] 336776

res
# # A tibble: 336,776 x 5                 # <--- no longer 'Source:   lazy query [?? x 5]'
# # Groups:   year, month, day [365]
#     year month   day dep_delay    rank
#    <int> <int> <int>     <dbl> <int64>
#  1  2013     1     1        NA       1
#  2  2013     1     1        NA       1
#  3  2013     1     1        NA       1
#  4  2013     1     1        NA       1
#  5  2013     1     1       853       5
#  6  2013     1     1       379       6
#  7  2013     1     1       290       7
#  8  2013     1     1       285       8
#  9  2013     1     1       260       9
# 10  2013     1     1       255      10
# # ... with 336,766 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SqlRender/vignettes/UsingSqlRender.pdf) of the package. So you can render a code with the SQL syntax.

Maybe the chunk of code below helps you:

```
library(dplyr)
library(SqlRender)
library(nycflights13)

ranked <- flights %>%
  group_by(year, month, day) %>%
  select(dep_delay) %>% 
  mutate(rank = rank(desc(dep_delay))) %>%
  ungroup()

sql <- "SELECT * FROM @x WHERE month = @a;"
render(sql, x = ranked, a = 2)
```

Comment: The OP is asking about the use of `dbplyr`, which does not require the user to generate SQL. Specifically, that package is about generating SQL *automatically* based on the `dplyr`-verbs and commands executed in the pipe. Your code here creates `ranked` from a local R object into a local R object, and then generates SQL that has nothing to do with the dplyr pipe.